# Can bagging and random subspaces method be used to assemble logistic regression models?

Tags: logistic, random-forest, bagging

I am after applications and theoretical knowledge of using bagging and random subspaces to assemble logistic regression models, just like how they are used to assemble decision trees to form a random forest model.

Some of the questions I would like answered are:

1) Can it be done?
2) Is it useful to do this? I ask this in the sense that random forests have proven themselves to be quite capable when benchmarked against other algorithms.
3) Does the result from random forests, that the out of bag error approximates cross validation error hold true if logistic regression models are used instead of decision trees?

Comment: You can do this and the error estimate will have similar properties. However since a sum of linear models is a single linear model the resultant model would still be equivalent to a single logistic regression and I'd expect it to converge to one fit by normal methods. People do bag neural networks and all sorts of other models though.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I think the only way the sum of logistic regression models will be a logistic regression model is if we consider them to be linear models in the log odds. However, if we use each LR model as a yes/no classifier, and assemble them using a voting mechanism, then would this not better approximate the random forest methodology?

Comment: Many (most?) rf implementations actually output the odds from each tree (ie the ratio in each class from each leaf) then average that, then choose a class. At least one paper has been written on the differences between this method and simple yes/no voting but they are pretty slight iirc. Incidently *boosting* with linear models is a thing and produces results related to LAR/LASSO: http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/bradfest.pdf

Comment: I have now found an R package and papers describing how to implement a version of this. Please see: http://labs.genetics.ucla.edu/horvath/htdocs/RGLM/ The answers to my questions can be found here.